# How to change Google results

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

I've made a website for a client. 
I've used WordPress. The problem is, that when you type the page's name in Google, you get two results:

1. Comments for [pagename]
2. Sample page (the one that WordPress makes by itself)

How do I make Google get the new sites and change those results?
I'm new to SEO.

Answer (score 1):

**You do not change Google results. Google changes Google results.**

This happens when Google crawls your site and updates its index. Depending on its priority, this can take from less than an hour to several weeks. At the beginning, before Google realizes how important your site is and how often it changes it will take longer. Just be patient.

Any new link to the website can help it along but the placement of that link is critical. If an article is posted in a news service about your new site for example, it will be found much faster is someone just comments on a random blog. If you have changed the site structure as opposed to the page layout, submitting a new sitemap through Google Webmaster Tools can help.

Comment: I've subimtted the new sitemap. 
Ok, so the results should be seen soon.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google would show your site shortly in results page. Because Google would takes some days to cache a page and display it on SERP. So if you did any changes in your website please wait and see the result.

Comment: I made lots of changes. So it should be visible in the next few days?

Comment: Yeah.. Surely it will display in the next few days.. So you don't worry about that..